# Images from iconList folder is not copying to .app file second time onwards

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

[image]

I want to update application.Problem is that when I am going to update application ,updated iconList folder is not copying  in .app file .I just want every time when i build application my updated iconList folder will be copy in .app file.Now it is not updating when i build application .I am simply deleting iconList folder in applicationdidfinishlaunching method and than copy new one from .app file.
How to achieve this task that on every application run my updated iconList will copied to .app file.

Comment: First check into build Phase that all the items are in bundle list?

Comment: I have checked in build phase.

Comment: is this happening in run time of changing the icon? Your question is not quite clear

Comment: No.Changing of icon is done before build.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but it seems like you need to clear the cache before creating .app file. Cleaning cache is easy Press Shift+Apple+K or select "Product->Clean" from file menu. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am cleaning cache but updated iconList is not copying to .app file.

Comment: what do you actually mean by iconList?

Comment: iconList is a folder in which sub folders and icons are residing

Comment: verify this by running your application on emulator. You can verify the files then as we can access the path where the app is installed on the emulator for debugging. This is the path '~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/'

Comment: I have saw already and after that i have posted question. Both in emulator and device as well using explorer

Answer (score 0):

see your iconlist folder colour is different then others . we will get this colour when we add files to the project by choosing the option "create folder references for any added folder's" as in image
[image] ,

i think that causing the problem . so try to add folder by selecting "create groups for any added folders" option

Comment: same result. It is not a reason for this.